# Is there a possibility to get all Labels with the same name except different number at the end of the name?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, arraylist, label

I designed a window with WPF, and so I used a lot of Labels. My question now is, if it is possible to get all Labels that are named like this: lblinch, lblinch1, lblinch2 ... .
Personally, I would like to store them in an array or in an arraylist. The Labels are not in the same parent-element except for "Window" and the first "Grid".

```
<Label Content="inch" Name="lblinch2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                            <Label Content="Distance between Beams Manual Input" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <TextBox Name="tbDistanceBeamsManualInput" Width="{x:Static local:Constants.TOOL_WIDTH}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,5" Background="Yellow" />
                            <Label Content="inch" Name="lblinch3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                            <Label Content="Bolt Hole Center to Column Wall * =" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <TextBox Name="tbBHoleCenterToColumnWall" Width="{x:Static local:Constants.TOOL_WIDTH}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,5" Background="Yellow" />
                            <Label Content="inch" Grid.Row="2" Name="lblinch4" Grid.Column="2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I'm doing to find controls of a specific type with a part of their `x:Name`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //find labels that have "lbl" in their name
            var labels = GetControlsByName<Label>(LabelsContainer, "lbl", new List<Label>());

            //do something with them
            foreach (var label in labels)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(label.Name);
            }
        }

        private List<T> GetControlsByName<T>(Visual root, string nameSearchTerm, List<T> result) where T : FrameworkElement
        {
            var childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);

            for (var i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var childVisual = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);

                if (childVisual is T control && control.Name.Contains(nameSearchTerm))
                {
                    result.Add(control);
                }

                GetControlsByName(childVisual, nameSearchTerm, result);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="LabelsContainer">
        <Label x:Name="lbl1" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="tbl1" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl2" />
        <Label x:Name="lbl3" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: var labels = GetControlsByName<Label>(LabelsContainer, "lbl", new()); --> here it gives me the following feedback: "represents a 2-tuple or pair as a value type. Use a tuple literal expression instead. Tuple must contain at least to elements". And so i can't really run the code.

Comment: @BebsiMaks that might be because my example uses NET 6.0. I've edited the example to be backwards compatible with older .NET releases. Try `var labels = GetControlsByName<Label>(LabelsContainer, "lbl", new List<Label>());` instead.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! I wish I could give you an arrow up, but I don't have enough reputation for that -_- . Have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 1):

First, name your parent `Grid`. ("RootGrid" in this case.)

```xml
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <Label x:Name="lblinch1" />
    <TextBlock />
    <Label x:Name="lblinch2" />
    <TextBox />
    <Label x:Name="lblinch3" />
    <Button />
    <Label x:Name="lblinch4" />
    <Label x:Name="lblinch5" />
</Grid>
```

Then use the `VisualTreeHelper` to get the children and filter them by their names.

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private List<Label> LabelControls { get; } = new();

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this.RootGrid);

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this.RootGrid, i) is Label label &&
                label.Name.StartsWith("lblinch") is true)
            {
                LabelControls.Add(label);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but to my understanding, doesn't this just get all Labels? Since I have got other Labels serving another matter, i would like to get only those that are named like in the description of the problem: lblinch, lblinch1, lblinch2 ..

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated the answer.

Comment: It tells me thatMainWindow doesnt contain a definition for RootGrid. And also I get this error caused by the same thing as in the comment from the other answer. Could it be because I have another .NET Version?

Comment: I updated my answer. You need to name the parent grid to access it from code-behind.

Comment: Michal Diviš's answer is better. It'll go deeper to find the elements in the target grid.

Comment: It worked too. Thanks a lot! I wish I could give you an arrow up, but I don't have enough reputation for that -_- . Have a wonderful day!